# Assigning the right value to the customerIDs in a sql function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a sql function for a flight customer database which calculates the bonus for customers. Suppose there is a table customer and a table reservations. If a customer reserves some seats on a flight, it will get a bonus with respect to the flight duration. If the customerID doesn't appear in the reservation table it will return the bonus otherwise it calculated the bonus.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `test5`(ID int(11) ) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN DECLARE result int;
    if (select ID from customer where ID not in (select CustomerID from reservation) limit 1) then set result = -1;
    else if (select ID from customer where ID in (select CustomerID from reservation) limit 1) then set result = (select sum(c.NoReservedSeats*f.FlightDurationInMinutes) as Bonus 
    from reservation c, flightexecution f where c.FlightNo=f.FlightNo 
    and f.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC = c.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC 
    and c.CustomerID = c.CustomerID group by c.CustomerID limit 1) ;
    end if;
    end if;
RETURN result;
END
```

So these are the bonus values for the CustomerIDs in the reservation table

```
+-------+
| Bonus |
+-------+
|   360 |
|   180 |
|  2280 |
|  2040 |
|   180 |
|  7180 |
+-------+
```

So the first if statement works, but second one doesn't work, I have to set limit 1 because otherwise get the "Error 1242 Subquery returns more than one row". But with this limit 1 expression I get for every customer 360 bonus which is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're not testing whether the ID parameter is in `reservations`. It should be:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE CustomerID = ID) 
THEN SET result = (SELECT ...)
ELSE SET result = -1
END IF;
RETURN result;
```

Also, you should avoid using the same name for a procedure parameter as a column in any of the tables you query. It can be confusing whether the name refers to the parameter or table column in the queries.